# How to make Cytoscape desktop interface font size larger?

Tags: cytoscape

How to change text size in Cytoscape 3? Not the font of the network labels, but the font of the GUI itself. I tried to look for it in preferences but there is nothing like it there.

Comment: Yup, it's totally inaccessible. Seems to not be paying any attention to window manager font sizes at all.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you running?  There is a way to do this on Windows and Linux by changing the system font size.  Not sure how to do it on Mac.

-- scooter